# how to convert € ’ “ ” into simple utf8 chars

Tags: php

i have scrapped posts from site and some times it the posts titles some strange chars came like this

```
 € ’ “ ”
```

and when i store them into database it store them like

```
â€™, â€œ, etc
```

how i can convert these chars into simple utf8-chars..

Any Help i have searched a lot but no one helped me so hopping so i will get answer from their.

And one more thing if you can't answer then please don't down vote this post.

Comment: So what have you searched a lot? What have you tried? What's the hexdump of your input vars? What's the database table definition, page output, meta charset, database connection charset?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the table to `UTF-8` so they're stored properly. You can also look into [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) if you don't have control over the database.